# Date range to months in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I’m trying to set my output to “Date not confirmed” if the date from MySQL = 2013-12-25 & $daydiff = "anything" and output "Not available" if the MySQL date = "NULL" & and $daydiff = "anything"

My code below doesn't seem to work, any suggestions or alternatives?

```
$ArrivalDate == $variants_data['ArrivalDate'];

$daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));


if ( $daydiff == '%wildcard%' && $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25') {
    $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
} 

elseif ( $daydiff == '%wildcard%' && $ArrivalDate == 'NULL') {
    $ETA ='Not available';
}

elseif ( $daydiff > 30 && $daydiff < 60 ) { // anything between 31 and 59 days is 1 month
    $ETA ='1 Month';
}

elseif ( $daydiff > 60 &&  $daydiff < 90  )  { // anything between 61 and 89 days is 2 months
    $ETA ='2 Months';
}

else
{
    $ETA ='';
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with '%wildcard%' ?

Comment: That's for any value.

Comment: so why put it in the if, if any value is ok? is 0 also acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are assign variables in your if clauses... Single "=" is assigning. I assume you want to check so you need "==" :)

```
if (!empty($daydiff) &&  $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25') {
   $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
} 

elseif (is_null($ArrivalDate) || $ArrivalDate == 'NULL') {
   $ETA ='Not available';
}
```

Comment: Ok but what exaclty is your ouptut? And where does '%wildcard%' come from?

Comment: '%wildcard%' = any value or anything ie -9 or 8

Comment: Ya but you are checking if $daydiff is equal to '%wildcard%'. Guess you want ``if(($daydiff >= -9 && $daydiff <= 8) && $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25') { $ETA = 'Date not confirmed'; }``

Comment: No, what he wants is !empty($daydiff) or maybe even $daydiff != 0

Comment: $daydiff is results from calculation so its not a fixed value. it can be any value.

Comment: @Chris, thanks that one worked :)

The issue is the rest of the code, it doesn't work

Comment: Glad you got it working! :) Dont forget to upvote and mark correct answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

What is your output? Always "Date Not Confirmed"?

I would guess so, because "=" does not compare strings:

```
if ( $daydiff = '%wildcard%' && $ArrivalDate = '2013-12-25') {
    $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
}
```

would be

```
if ( $daydiff == '%wildcard%' && $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25') {
    $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
}
```

But then, '%wildcard%' is not something, PHP replaces by 'anything'. So, what is your exact error? If it does not matter, what $daydiff is, just leave it out of your condition.

Comment: Thanks @jens - i've tried "==" but not getting the results. There is no error but I cant get the required results. $daydiff is the number of days, i dont want to put ie 55 days but i'd rather say within 2months or 2 months.